# disruptor consumers not working as expected

Tags: java, multithreading, disruptor-pattern

When I run this code

```
    public class Test {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        Disruptor<MyEvent> disruptor = new Disruptor<MyEvent>(new EventFactoryImpl<MyEvent>(),
    Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2), new MultiThreadedClaimStrategy(32), new                    BusySpinWaitStrategy());

        MyEventHandler myEventHandler1 = new MyEventHandler("1");
        MyEventHandler myEventHandler2 = new MyEventHandler("2");

        disruptor.handleEventsWith(myEventHandler1, myEventHandler2);
        RingBuffer<MyEvent> ringBuffer = disruptor.start();

        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(8);

        for (long l = 0; l < 2; l++) {
          bb.putLong(0, l);
          long sequence = ringBuffer.next();

          try {
             MyEvent event = ringBuffer.get(sequence);
             event.set(bb.getLong(0));
          }
          finally {
            ringBuffer.publish(sequence);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    public class MyEvent {
      private long value;

      public void set(long value) {
        this.value = value;
      }

      public long get() {
        return value;
      }
    }

    public class MyEventHandler implements EventHandler<MyEvent> {
       private String id;

       public MyEventHandler(String id) {
          this.id = id;
       }

       public void onEvent(MyEvent event, long sequence, boolean endOfBatch) {
           System.out.println("id: " + id + ", event: " + event.get() + ", sequence: " + sequence +                  "," + Thread.currentThread().getName());
       }
    }

    public class EventFactoryImpl<T> implements EventFactory<T> {
       @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
       public T newInstance() {
         return (T) new MyEvent();
       }
    }
```

I'm getting this output

```
id: 1, event: 0, sequence: 0,pool-1-thread-1
id: 1, event: 1, sequence: 1,pool-1-thread-1
id: 2, event: 0, sequence: 0,pool-1-thread-2
id: 2, event: 1, sequence: 1,pool-1-thread-2
```

But I expected each event to be processed by a separate thread just once. How can I make it happen?

Answer (score 1):

With the Disruptor, each `EventHandler` subscribed to the ring buffer will read each message once.

If you want to have multiple threads processing messages as they come out of the ring buffer, there are a couple of options.  The first and best option is to set up a separate `Disruptor` for each reader thread, and have the writer alternate between buffers in a round robin fashion.  If you must use a single ring buffer (perhaps to sequence the events), then you could set the thread ID which *should* process each event onto the events themselves (again in an alternating fashion), and have the threads which do not match that ID discard the event.

Answer (score 1):

Each `EventHandler` will process each and every event. You have the option of chaining `EventHandler`s so that they act on the processed state from the previous handlers in the chain.

The disruptor also [provides](https://github.com/LMAX-Exchange/disruptor/blob/master/src/main/java/com/lmax/disruptor/WorkerPool.java) a `WorkerPool` which is designed to spread events across a pool of workers.